# Stop a filtered select box from resetting after on click submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My Setup:**

I have a jquery script which is being used to filter what appears in the select boxes (this works fine).
For the filtered select boxes I also have a submit on click for each option in the select box

I believe the "on click submit" is breaking the filtering but i wish to keep the "on click submit" for ease of use.

**Issue:**

After I select an option from the list, the options from the other select boxes (geotrust and thawte) get filtered as expected but then after i select an option from the filtered list, the list is reset.

I would like it to remain filtered even after i make a selection - is it possible?

Unfortunately, it couldn't be replicated in jsfiddle as form submissions return an error so you need to save the files locally to test..

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="cookie_used_false">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Product Comparison</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script3.js"></script>
</head><body>
<form id="compare">
<select id="filter">
    <option value="all">Show All</option>
    <option value="dv">Show DV</option>
    <option value="ov">Show OV</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="geotrust" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option class="gt_dv">qssl</option>
    <option class="gt_ov">tbizid</option>
    <option class="tht_dv">ssl123</option>
    <option class="tht_ov">sslweb</option>
</select>
<select id="thawte" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option class="gt_dv">qssl</option>
    <option class="gt_ov">tbizid</option>
    <option class="tht_dv">ssl123</option>
    <option class="tht_ov">sslweb</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$.fn.optVisible = function(stateVal) {
    var isBool = typeof stateVal === "boolean";
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (isBool) {
            if (stateVal) $this.filter("span > option").unwrap();
            else $this.filter(":not(span > option)").wrap("<span>").parent().hide();
        }
        else {
            $this.filter("span > option").toggleOptionVisibility(true);
            $this.filter(":not(span > option)").toggleOptionVisibility(false);
        }
    });
}

jQuery( document ).ready( function(){

    $("#filter").change(function(){
        if ($("#filter option[value='all']").is(':selected')) { 
            alert('all');
            $( "#geotrust option" ).optVisible( true );
            $( "#thawte option" ).optVisible( true );
         }
        if ($("#filter option[value='dv']").is(':selected')) {
            $("[class*='dv']").optVisible( true );
            $("[class*='ov']").optVisible( false );
         }
        if ($("#filter option[value='ov']").is(':selected')) {
            $("[class*='ov']").optVisible( true );
            $("[class*='dv']").optVisible( false );
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Selects are reset because there is a page reload after you choose from the filtered select. Remove submit event from onchange handlers and implement a button to submit a form once everything is selected. Or a desired workflow is different?

Comment: I realized i need to change the workflow and use ajax to post the values to php - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676903/how-to-get-value-from-form-without-submitting-it

Comment: If you need chained/dependent select to be populated with data fetched from backend depending on previous select choice - then Ajax is the right way to go.