# PHP - Using getElementByID or $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have a WordPress theme which uses a combination of PHP/JS/AJAX to present a booking form.

I am trying to access the value of an output field which is rendered by the following:

```
<div class="output">
    <p><?php _e('Check-in', 'bookyourtravel') ?></p>
    <p class="step_1_date_from_holder" id="pccfromdate"></p>
    <p><?php if (!empty($accommodation_check_in_time)) { echo ' ' . $accommodation_check_in_time; } ?></p>
</div>
```

I need to get the value from the pccfromdate text. The variables that I have seen through the booking process at http://epiccloudshare.com/penninelettings/hotel/curlew-yurt-village/ are as follows:

`$date_from` (set up in a .js file)

`$selected_date_from` (seen when I do a Chrome "inspect element")

I have tried

```
<?php $date_from2 = document.getElementByID('pccfromdate').value; ?>
```

but if my understanding is starting to develop, this is not possible because PHP is server side and JS is client side

The form has a POST method against it so I also tried

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['selected_date_from']))
    $date_from2 = $_POST['selected_date_from']; ?>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated

EDIT

I did not indicate that the `$_POST` attempt did not work either.
So, as indicated by machavity I **think** the answer is something to do with AJAX as the value I require is displayed via the `step_1_date_from_holder` class. I am able to modify the php script to assign a `name` and/or `id` to the `<p>` but I haven't got a clue as to how to use AJAX to get at the actual value to get it back into a PHP variable.

Comment: One way to do something like this would be to use AJAX.

Comment: Sidenote: The function is `getElementById()` and not `getElementByID()` it's case-sensitive. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById and you can't inject JS into PHP like that.

Comment: If you want to access a POST array, then you will need a name attribute for the form element(s). I.e.: `name="selected_date_from"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get VALUE from FORM without Submitting it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676903/how-to-get-value-from-form-without-submitting-it)

Comment: Is 'pccffromdate' a form input (when being posted to the output page)? E.g. `input type="text"`, `select` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `getElementById()` is a JavaScript function, and therefore using it inside PHP code will not work.

If you are trying to access a `$_POST` variable, this is quite simple to do:

- Observe the form you are working with, and look at the `name` attribute's value. For instance, `name="foo"` can be accessed with `$_POST['foo']`, or;
- Use `print_r($_POST);` to echo the `$_POST` array.

Remember to use something like [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape user input.