# Pass Value between pages in Php

Tags: php

I want to pass the value from this page to next page `pay.php` file below is my form (index.php )

```
<form action=\"/modules/gateways/pay.php\" method=\"post\" id=\"checkout[id]\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"user\" value=\"[userid]\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"decription\" value=\"[itemname]\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount\" id=\"amount[id]\" value=\"[price]\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"type\" value=\"deposit\">
</form>
```

and in pay.php, I am trying to get the value with this code:

```
$m_amount = number_format($_POST['amount'], 2, ".", "");
$m_desc = strip_tags($_POST['decription']);
```

I am not getting values in pay.php.

Comment: ho do you submit this form?

Comment: try with `$_REQUEST[]`

Comment: Why are all the quotes escaped? Are you outputting that HTML using echo in PHP? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: that form is submitting using form action, tried with $_REQEUST but no luck.Yes outputting

Comment: work or not @Mithu

Comment: You need to show us _all_ the relevant code. Show us the code that's outputting the form, the code that submits the form and all the code that receives the posted form.

Comment: Bhargav Not working

Comment: any error? And check value assign or not to text box

Comment: no error! i have tried with a fixed value also as like value="10.00" From first page but it is 0 value in the next page always

Comment: where is your submit button?

Comment: Does anybody else think that this form is broken? Mainly because there is no submit button, but also because all the fields are hidden? Also the id's and values for form elements seem to be really strange. Like not working as intended strange

Comment: that may be one of the reason.But i need to pass the value in this way without a submit button and don't know how to pass this value

Comment: Again, you _need to show us all the relevant code_. We're not here to guess what the rest looks like. You should also explain what it it is you're trying to do and why. That will make it easier for us to come up with alternative solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get VALUE from FORM without Submitting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676903/how-to-get-value-from-form-without-submitting-it)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your HTML.

```
<form action="/modules/gateways/pay.php" method="post" id="checkout[id]">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" name="decription" value="itemone">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount_id" value="538">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="deposit">
</form>
```

and in pay.php try to receive to simply print POST variable

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Include JQuery or a similar JS framework or use native JS to submit this form.
Without a submit-button you have to submit this form by JS or a JS-framework.

In JQuery you have to write something similar to this example:

```
   $('#checkout[FORMID]').submit();
```

This will submit the form. **For sure you have to complete this but basicly this is the missing call.**

I saw your form contains hidden inputs. If this form depends on another form/action or else you should either include the hidden form in the depoending form or submit it by itself using JS/JQuery/something similar.